# Syntax highlighting in code blocks

Tags: support

How can I get some proper syntax highlighting when posting e.g. powershell code in my questions?

I had a look at `How to format your text` but apparently coudn't find the answer. I usually mark the code and hit CTRL+k on the keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand it, there is not yet support for powershell in the [JavaScript library](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) used by SE to implement this.

See the [meta page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) about the general feature and [this discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214232/please-add-support-for-powershell-syntax-highlighting) about Powershell in particular.

Comment: I usually just use lang-cs when doing PS. It's close enough.